# Chemical potential for BE condensate: why the normalization would (uncorrectly) give $\mu> 0$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, normalization, chemical-potential

Consider a gas of bosons. Let $g(\epsilon)$ be the distribution of energy levels (degeneracy). Consider the following integral
$$I(\beta,\mu)=\int{d\epsilon g(\epsilon}) \frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}-1}=1$$
It must be equal to $1$ and the chemical potential $\mu $ is "defined" by this normalization. In this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11925533_Bose-Einstein_Condensation_in_Complex_Networks it is said that, for $T<T_{BE condensation}$, "the equation $I(\beta,\mu)=1$ has no solution for $\mu$" and this is indeed a "signature of BE condensation".

But I suppose it means that there are no **negative** solutions for $\mu$, since I suppose there would be positive solutions, but they cannot be accepted, since in a bosons gas we always have $\mu \leq 0$, even in BE condensation phase. Is this correct?

If so, then why the model in the paper predict also positive solutions for $\mu$ for  $T<T_{BE condensation}$?

My guess is that, if we are in BE condensation (i.e. $T<T_{BE condensation}$), then there are $N_0(T)$ bosons exactly at zero energy. Since the integral is from $0$ to $\infty$ it does not take in to account those bosons at zero energy, therefore, for $T<T_{BE condensation}$ it does not makes sense to request  $I(\beta,\mu)=1$, since it should be $I(\beta,\mu)+N_0(T)/N=1$. From here the  unacceptable value of $\mu$.

But if this is correct, then, I think that maybe also at $T>T_{BE condensation}$ the integral would not count the number of bosons at zero energy (and there are some zero energy bosons even at $T>T_{BE condensation}$), and it shouldn't work either for $T>T_{BE condensation}$? i.e. also at $T>T_{BE condensation}$ the normalization $I(\beta,\mu)=1$ should be written instead as $I(\beta,\mu)+N_0(T)/N=1$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you say that integral is $1$? It should be the number density of bosons.

Comment: I assume that the specific volume is 1